# OpenVPN Connect to IPSEC

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn

On my Raspberry Pi I have OpenVPN installed and configured a VPN-Connection to my VPN-Proivder as a Service. This works flawlessly. Now, for some scripts I need to be connected to my Parents Local Area Network. The Router of theirs provides a VPN function but I only get IPSEC-login-data. On macOS and iOS I can connect to their VPN. I have created a VPN-Config-File like this (found this on a website while looking for a solution):

```
IPSec gateway <VPN-IP>
IPSec ID <vpn_user>
IPSec secret <Shared_Secret>
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username <vpn_user>
Xauth password <passwort>
local port 0
DPD idle timeout (our side) 0
```

Now how do I set this VPN-Connection as a service (if it's not possible via OpenVPN that's fine but I need to have a service which I can start and stop via systemctl)

Comment: OpenVPN and IPSec are completely different types of VPN. There is absolutely no way they can talk to each other. Try Network Manager

Comment: I will take a look at it. Is it possible to have multiple VPN-services running (OpenVPN AND Network Manager) when only one VPN is connected ?

Comment: OpenVPN is a VPN service. Network Manager is not a VPN service - it controls network connectivity including the use of VPNs.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN is a different type of Virtual Private Network protocol. In order to connect to a VPN server using the IPSec protocol from a GNU/Linux system, you could utilize [OpenConnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/), which not only supports IPSec, but also integrates with NetworkManager.